# Definition of continuity and big O notation

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Suppose that a real valued function $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. Then, the epsilon delta definition says that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0 $ such that $|f(x_0)-f(x)| < \epsilon $ whenver $|x-x_0| < \delta$.

Based on this definition, how do I show that $f(x_0+h)-f(x_0) = O(h)$? That is, $|f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)| \leq C h$ for some constant $C$ and all $h$ such that $h \leq h_0$ for some $h_0$?

$f$ needs not be differentiable, so I cannot really use the Taylor's theorem here.

Comment: This is true if $f$ is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The statement is not true. Take for example the function $\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,\infty)$. It is continuous at $0$ but
$$|\sqrt{0 + h} -\sqrt{0} | = \sqrt{h},$$
which can't be bounded by $C\,h$ for $h\leq h_0$ for any $C$ and $h_0$.

Answer (score 6):

- This is true if $f$ is *differentiable* at $x_0$:
  in this case, you have
  $$
  \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h} \xrightarrow[h\to0]{} f'(x_0)
  $$
  from which $\lvert f(x_0+h)-f(x_0) \rvert = O(h)$.
- This is still true if $f$ is only *Lipschitz* (on a neighborhood of $x_0$):
  then, there is a constant $C\geq0$ such that
  $$
  \lvert f(x_0+h)-f(x_0) \rvert \leq C \lvert h \rvert
  $$
  from which $\lvert f(x_0+h)-f(x_0) \rvert = O(h)$.
- This is **false** in general: *continuity alone* is not strong enough an assumption. [Rastapopoulos' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2118145/75808) gives the counterexample of the function $\sqrt{\cdot}$ at $x_0=0$ *(and this will work also with any $x\mapsto x^\alpha$ for $\alpha\in(0,1)$, for instance)*; but basically, all you can say from continuity is
  $$
  \lvert f(x_0+h)-f(x_0) \rvert = o(1)
  $$
  which is a much weaker statement than $O(h)$.