# Finite difference error for twice differentiable function

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, finite-differences, numerical-calculus

Assume that $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$. Then I want to approximate $f''$ by some finite difference as
\begin{align}
f''(x)\approx\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}
\end{align}
But since $f$ has only two derivatives, a Taylor expansion shows that
\begin{align}
f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac{1}{2}f''(x+\Theta h)h^2,\qquad \Theta\in (0,1).
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}=\frac{1}{2}(f''(x+\Theta h)+f''(x-\tilde{\Theta}h))
\end{align}
So is there a way to get some error like
\begin{align}
f''(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}+ O(h)?
\end{align}
which would be easy by Taylor's theorem if $f\in C^3(\mathbb{R})$ but I cannot assume this here. I only see because of continuity of $f''$ that
\begin{align}
f''(x+\Theta h)=f''(x) + o(1),\quad h\downarrow 0.
\end{align}

Comment: This is a second order scheme. If you expand $f(x+h)$ and $f(x-h)$ but up to order of 4 and substitute into the approximation formula you have, the remaining highest order error term will be of $O(h^2)$.

Comment: By expansion you mean the taylor approximation, don't you, but this would require higher order differentiablility, right? As I pointed out, this is not possible here.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked :(

Comment: I think this post maybe helpful? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118132/definition-of-continuity-and-big-o-notation

Comment: I believe that under these assumptions $$f(x + h) = f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac{{h^2 }}{2}f''(x) + o(h^2 )$$ is the best you can say in general.

Answer (score 1):

So [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) says the following: For $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ you can control
$$f(x \pm h) = f(x) \pm  f'(x) h + \frac{1}{2}f''(x)h^2 + p(x)h^2$$
which is the Peano form of the remainder.
For this particular formulation, your error
$$E := f''(x) - \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2} $$
is of order $1$.

You could take a look at [other forms of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder). Mean-value formulas of the remainder based on $f'''$ are by assumption clearly invalid.
However, if $f''$ is absolutely continuous and $f'''$ is integrable (but not continuously differentiable) you could use a integral form of the remainder. However, this is also of Order $h^2$, thus your overall error will again be or order $1$.